# Problems with the colors on my screen. How can I check if it's a hardware problem?

Tags: hardware, 11.04, graphics, colors

On my EEE PC netbook some colors are not displayed properly. Specifically, dark gradients such as in the window title do not look very smooth, but rather look like a sequence of a couple of different colors.

This is especially visible when opening a menu, for example the "File" menu in Firefox. As you know this one is black, and it looks terrible on my screen. It is not just black, but the colors look really graded and far from a smooth gradient or anything.

Now I am wondering: Is this a hardware or software issue? And how can I check this?
If it should be a fixable problem I think it would be worth another question.

Note that I am using Natty. If my problem description is not good enough I can try to take a photo.

Comment: It sounds like your resolution is lower than your screens optimum and it's pixelated.  That's just my take on the description.

Comment: Color depth rather than resolution methinks....

Comment: It is definitely not the resolution. It might be a color depth compatibility issue with Natty, do you know where I can adjust that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the Netbook screen is at fault, you can try plugging it into an external monitor. If the colors appear fine on the monitor, you may have some screen issues.

To check your video card, I would try a different version of Ubuntu, for starters. You don't have to reinstall to test this out - [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) should let you boot into a live session, which will allow you to try one of the more stable versions, like 10.04. I run an EEE Netbook on that version, so I believe it should work. If it does look like there's a software issue with 11.04, please file a bug to help the developers out!

As many folks here have mentioned in the comments, it seems like this would (most likely) be an issue of color depth. Your video card can support a wide variety of color ranges, and it sounds like you might have yours set to one of the lower ones.

Comment: Cheers, good answer. In 10.10 I get proper colors, although I have to say the EEE PC's screen is not... the best...
Nevermind, do you know how to adjust the color depth easily?

Comment: Honestly, not really - I don't use either major desktop environment, so I wouldn't know where to look in there. Also, it could be an X.org setting (like in modelines or something), but I usually just go through nvidia-settings. Sounds like a great second question to post here, though... :)